# React-Navigation Android deep linking not working

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation, deep-linking

I'm using react-navigation@3.0.0 in my react-native app, I've followed the deep linking guide https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/deep-linking.html.

iOS works as expected but I'm getting funny results for android.

When I run:

```
adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "appscheme://apphost/some/path" com.app.bundle
```

I get following warning , `Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front. (AndroidManifest has android:launchMode="singleTask")`

followed by:

`Status: ok
Activity: com.app.bundle/.MainActivity
ThisTime: 203
TotalTime: 203
WaitTime: 207
Complete`

But all that appears to happen is the app re-boots without actually navigating to the path.

Has anyone figured out how `react-navigation 2.x/3.0.0` does android deep links?

Big thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found that it is important to pass the prop uriPrefix:

`<PrimaryNav uriPrefix={prefix} />`

directly to the component that does `createStackNavigator()`

in my case I was doing it in the App.js but moved it to the navigations/index.js

Comment: can you please elaborate about it? what is "prefix", can you post a snippet of your code?

Comment: @gor this is the documentation that explains what prefix is: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/deep-linking.html